# WPF MVVM Validation in Model & Controls

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have a WPF Application with a MVVM architecture. The viewmodels implement IDataErrorInfo with an implementation that will add errors from nested viewmodels. SaveCommand will check the Error of the topmost viewmodel and show a error MesssageBox if anything is amiss with a list of all errors.

That works fine for errors checked by business logic (like mandatory fields) but won't deal with conversion errors when e.g. the user enters a name into a TextBox bound to a numeric property.

Is there a good way/library that combines Errors from the ViewModel and those that are indicated in the UI but don't actually reach the viewmodel? Falling back to all string properties in viewmodel so conversion can be done there feels just wrong. I thought about going through the logical control tree to get a list of all errors that are caused by conversion errros and then combine this list with the INotifyDataInfo errorMessage but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: A lot issues like this can be resolved by using an appropriate control, if the user is supposed to enter a value between 1 and 100 why use a text box when a slider is designed for just that, the view models shouldn't be validating the view, it only validates the data passed to it by the view. so any library that does what you want would violate MVVM

Comment: *user enters a name into a TextBox bound to a numeric property* wat that should show an error in the UI automatically

Comment: It shows an error in the control but the view model knows nothing about it since the error comes from value conversion of the binding. So the viewmodel that relies on it's own IDataErrorInfo to be valid when Save is called will perform a save with the unchanged value while some controls show binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom `ValidationRule` and associate this with the `Binding` object to customize the behaviour or this validation. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/.

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:StringToIntValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    ...
</TextBox>
```

**C#:**

```
public class StringToIntValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid integer value.");
    }
}
```

Also note that this kind of validation takes place in the view or control. It is not the responsibility of the view model to make sure that the view can set the value of a public property that the view model exposes.

It simply exposes the property and it is the responsibility of the view to set it and of course it must set it to a value of the correct type.